# existence of partial derivative at (0,0)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I've got to find out if the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)= \sqrt[3]{5x(x^2+y^2)}$ exist:

I've differentiated normally with all the rules,where I get:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{5}(3x^2+y^2)}{3(x(x^2+y^2))^{2/3}}$ 
and 
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\dfrac{2\sqrt[3]{5}xy}{3(x(x^2+y^2))^{2/3}}$.

Obviously, I cannot put in $(0,0)$ as it's not defined there.

With the limit calculations I get:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\displaystyle \lim_{(t,0) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=\displaystyle \lim_{(t,0) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sqrt[3]{5t(t^2)}}{t}=\sqrt[3]{5}$

And

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$

What does that mean?  That the partial derivatives exist or do not exist? I'm confused because of all the definitions.

Comment: They exist as you use the definition and it brings a nice result. The algorithm to find derivatives of functions fails in some cases, as you can see.

Comment: Will the definition sometimes fail to bring a result? I'm asked whether a certain function has partial derivates, and it seems to me the limit definition will always yield *some* result.